# How can I install the IIS Management Console on Windows 7 Home Basic?

Tags: windows-7, installation, iis-7

I would like to install the inet manager for Windows 7, but I get a message that I need to install the IIS management console first, and I can't figure out how.

So, how do I install the IIS Management Console on my Windows 7 Home Basic edition machine?

Answer (score 2):

> How can i install Management Consol in my machine.

Upgrade to Windows 7 Home Premium and then install the Management Console. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753473.aspx) for this justification.

Comment: Home Basic and Starter editions does not have IIS Management Console.

Comment: That's why he has to upgrade to Home Premium...

Answer (score 1):

Now you can also use WebMatrix which includes IIS Developer Express and will give you a simpler Management experience and the full functionality of IIS 7.5 even for Starter and Basic editions (including XP). Its only 8 MB and free: http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/

Answer (score 0):

Apart from upgrading Windows, you can also use the free [Apache](http://www.apache.org/) web server.

See [Using Apache With Microsoft Windows](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/platform/windows.html).